# jQuery Checkbox class attribute

Tags: jquery, class, checkbox, filter

how do you access the class attribute of a `<asp:Checkbox>` in a jQuery selector statement?

for example

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbTest" Text="Cb Test" FieldName="1st Test Check Box" class="toggleBox"/>
```

this:

```
$(':checkbox').toggleAttr("checked", true, false)
```

accesses the checkbox and applies a custom function to the checked attribute but if i want to filter based on a certain class how do i access/filter based on that?

Comment: He has mentioned about that custom function in the posting.

Comment: Oh, good. I wasn't paying attention. I guess I assumed selectors come before plugins.

Answer (score 5):

`<asp:checkbox>` is rendered as `<input type="checkbox" />`. So you can use a [**element selector**](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) followed by a [**:chekbox selector**](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) and then a [**class selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

```
$("input:checkbox.toggleBox")
```

will get you the desired checkbox with class name toggleBox.

See [**class selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

***Note***

`$(':checkbox')` is equivalent to `$('*:checkbox')`, so `$('input:checkbox')` should be used instead.

Comment: @mike, make note: this answer is applicable for a lot more than jquery and this specific checkbox example.  It's one of the underlying mechanisms for css selectors.  Learn these concepts well, you will use them everywhere throughout your work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function chkbxch(valor) {
            //$('.ChChecar input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
            $.each($('.Ch' + valor + ' input:checkbox'), function () {
                if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                    $(this).attr('checked', false);
                } else {
                    $(this).attr('checked', true);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: That'll fail in jQuery 1.6 and 1.7.  You need to use .prop(), not .attr().  .attr() will give you the value when the node was first created, not the current value.

Comment: +1 for the chkbxch post and the subsequent comment, this solved my problem. Incidentally I used neither attr or prop, but removeAttr which seems to work well, although I realise that thread is 4 years old!